# How do I make the program stop only when something specific happens?

Tags: python

I just started coding and i want to write a small program were you have to guess a number. The problem is you basically only have one guess and then it tells you the right number. How do I make the program only stop as soon as the user guessed the right number?

This is my current code:

```
import random

a = int(input())

x = random.randint(1,5)

if a > x:
    print("you guessed to high")

elif a < x:
    print("you guessed to low")

elif a == x:
    print("you guessed right")
```

I have tried 'while' but it didn't work.

Comment: Please update your question with your code which `"it didn't work"`.

Comment: A while loop. While(input is not x) { ask user for input; give user feedback }

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can figure what is happening

```py
import random

x = random.randint(1,5)

guessed_right = False

while not guessed_right:

    a = int(input())

    if a > x:
        print("you guessed to high")

    elif a < x:
        print("you guessed to low")

    elif a == x:
        print("you guessed right")
        guessed_right = True
```